# Headphones Don't work

Tags: 11.10, sound, hardware, headphones, volume-control

I have a problem. The computer speakers work fine, but when I connect the headphones I can't hear anything. I have a Packard Bell EasyNote MZ35-F with Ubuntu 11.10 (kernel 3.0.0-16-generic).

Here is some info about my PC that may help find a solution:

```
$ lspci
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
```

```
$ sudo lshw
deathnotebook
description: Notebook
version: ????????
width: 32 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 smp-1.4 smp
configuration: administrator_password=enabled boot=oem-specific chassis=notebook cpus=1 frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=unknown power-on_password=disabled uuid=80ED58E6-0886-DB11-8000-4E45435F4349
*-core
description: Motherboard
product: **EasyNote MZ35**
vendor: **Packard Bell BV**
physical id: 0
version: D3B
serial: QPCPCB64311369??????????????????
*-firmware
description: BIOS
vendor: Packard Bell
physical id: 0
version: V0.12
date: 10/23/2006
size: 102KiB
capacity: 960KiB
capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification
*-cpu
description: CPU
product: **Intel(R) Celeron(R) M CPU 410 @ 1.46GHz**
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 4
bus info: cpu@0
version: 6.14.8
serial: 0000-06E8-0000-0000-0000-0000
slot: U23
size: 1460MHz
capacity: 1460MHz
width: 32 bits
clock: 100MHz
capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe constant_tsc up arch_perfmon bts aperfmperf pni monitor tm2 xtpr pdcm
*-multimedia
description: Audio device
product: **IXP SB4x0 High Definition Audio Controller**
vendor: **ATI Technologies Inc**
physical id: 14.2
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=64
resources: irq:40 memory:c0400000-c0403fff
```

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC861-VD
Codec: LSI ID 1040
```

```
$ sudo aplay -l
tarjeta 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], dispositivo 0: ALC861-VD Analog [ALC861-VD Analog]
Subdispositivos: 0/1
Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `alsamixer` and turn up the volume for the `Headphone` slider. I've seen pulseaudio mute this setting way too often for me. Quit alsamixer by pressing `esc`

Comment: alsamixer dont show a option of headphone, only master,pcm,mic,mic boost and beep

Answer (score 0):

The answer regarding the headphones may be here at [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=e1f3e586c879c943243877e5fdecab36&p=9896318&postcount=1). This solution worked for me on my Packard Bell EasyNote MZ35-U-005.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference